# Understanding the way from hid usage id to gdk keyval on Linux

Tags: linux, hid, gdk

I wanted to understand the way from the hid usage id of a keyboard through the system up to a GDK keyval inclusive layout translation. Or to be more specific: I have a UTF-8 string and wan't to create a list of hid keys a external device has to play to get the same result.

What I tried so far:

(Stripped down version without shift/alt handling)

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GdkKeymapKey *get_key_with_group_0(GdkKeymapKey *keys, gint n_keys) {
gint i;

for (i = 0; i < n_keys; ++i)
    if (keys[i].group == 0)
        return &keys[i];

/* fallback: return first element */
g_warning("can't find keycode for group 0");
return keys;
}

static guint keycode_to_keyval(guint keycode) {
GdkKeymap *keymap;
GdkKeymapKey key = {keycode, 0, 0};
guint keyval;

keymap = gdk_keymap_get_default();
keyval = gdk_keymap_lookup_key(keymap, &key);
if (keyval == 0)
    g_warning("keycode %i has no keyval!\n", keycode);
return keyval;
}

/* Hid usage tables v1.12 chapter 10 and /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gdk/gdkkeysyms.h */
/* stores keyvals without modifiers */
static guint const table_hid_usage_id_to_keyval[232] = {
/*   0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       A       B       C       D       E       F */
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0061, 0x0062, 0x0063, 0x0064, 0x0065, 0x0066, 0x0067, 0x0068, 0x0069, 0x006a, 0x006b, 0x006c, /* 0 */
0x006d, 0x006e, 0x006f, 0x0070, 0x0071, 0x0072, 0x0073, 0x0074, 0x0075, 0x0076, 0x0077, 0x0078, 0x0079, 0x007a, 0x0031, 0x0032, /* 1 */
0x0033, 0x0034, 0x0035, 0x0036, 0x0037, 0x0038, 0x0039, 0x0030, 0xff0d, 0xff1b, 0xff08, 0xff09, 0x0020, 0x00df, 0x00b4, 0x00fc, /* 2 */
0x002b, 0x005c, 0x0023, 0x00f6, 0x00e4, 0x005e, 0x002c, 0x002e, 0x002d, 0xffe5, 0xffbe, 0xffbf, 0xffc0, 0xffc1, 0xffc2, 0xffc3, /* 3 */
0xffc4, 0xffc5, 0xffc6, 0xffc7, 0xffc8, 0xffc9, 0x0000, 0xff14, 0xff13, 0xff63, 0xff50, 0xff55, 0xffff, 0xff57, 0xff56, 0xff53, /* 4 */
0xff51, 0xff54, 0xff52, 0xff7f, 0xffaf, 0xffaa, 0xffad, 0xffab, 0xff8d, 0xff9c, 0xff99, 0xff9b, 0xff96, 0xff9d, 0xff98, 0xff95, /* 5 */
0xff97, 0xff9a, 0xff9e, 0xff9f, 0x003c, 0xff67, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xffca, 0xffcb, 0xffcc, 0xffcd, 0xffce, 0xffcf, 0xffd0, 0xffd1, /* 6 */
0xffd2, 0xffd3, 0xffd4, 0xffd5, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, /* 7 */
0x0000, 0x0000, 0xffe5, 0x0000, 0xff14, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, /* 8 */
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, /* 9 */
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, /* A */
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xff89, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, /* B */
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xff80, 0x0000, 0x0000, /* C */
0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0xffae, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000, /* D */
0xffe3, 0xffe1, 0xffe9, 0xffeb, 0xffe4, 0xffe2, 0xffea, 0xff67 /* E */
};

// Needs keyval without modifications
static guint8 keyval_to_hid(guint keyval) {
guint i;
for (i = 0; i < 232; ++i) {
    if (table_hid_usage_id_to_keyval[i] == keyval)
        return i;
}
return 0;
}

static void do_it(gchar const *text) {
gchar const *iter;
guint keyval;
gunichar character;
GdkKeymapKey *keys;
GdkKeymapKey *key;
gint n_keys;
GdkKeymap *keymap;

iter = text;

keymap = gdk_keymap_get_default();

while(TRUE) {
    character = g_utf8_get_char_validated(iter, -1);
    if (character == 0)
        break;

    keyval = gdk_unicode_to_keyval(character);

            /* get keyval without modifications */
    if (!gdk_keymap_get_entries_for_keyval(keymap, keyval, &keys, &n_keys)) {
        g_warning("keyval 0x%04x has no keycode!", keyval);
        iter = g_utf8_find_next_char(iter, NULL);
        break;
    }
    key = get_key_with_group_0(keys, n_keys);
    keyval = keycode_to_keyval(key->keycode);

    g_print("0x%04x\n", keyval_to_hid(keyval));

    g_free(keys);

    iter = g_utf8_find_next_char(iter, NULL);
}
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
g_type_init();
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

do_it("Testing z");

return 0;
}
```

My problem:

Where and how is keyboard layout translation done?
On my german keyboard I get this:

1. Pressing the "z" Button
2. Device sends HID usage id 0x1c (y and Y)
3. xev says keycode 29; keysym 0x7a; "z"

Where is this translation done, and how can I go back this way?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

The keycode that GTK returns is the keycode X uses, which is independent of the keymap.
Conversion of xkeycode to keyval and back to hid usage id via static lookup is wrong since keyval is keymap dependent.

The xkeycode can be transferred back to kernel keycode with a static table[1]. Further conversion of kernel keycode to hid usage id is also done with static table[2].

[1]http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2006-June/015633.html

[2]https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/hid/hid-input.c?id=refs/tags/v3.9